Angular doesn't detect property change on button click
I'm using Angular 17 and I have a noob question. In my component's template, the table's footer has a couple of buttons and a spinner, which has visibility: hidden at the beginning:
    <ng-container matColumnDef="created_on">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Created On</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.created_on}}</td>
      <td mat-footer-cell ...>
        <div class="tfooter">
          <mat-paginator
            ...
          >
          </mat-paginator>
          <div class="btn-actions">
            <mat-spinner
              diameter="35"
              strokeWidth="4"
              [style.visibility]="isDeleting ? 'show' : 'hidden'"
            >
            </mat-spinner>
            <button
              ...
            >
              Switch DB
            </button>
            <button
              mat-flat-button
              color="warn"
              (click)="doStuff()"
            >
              Do Stuff
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

Here is the component:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-change-db',
  templateUrl: './change-db.component.html',
  styleUrl: './change-db.component.css'
})
export class ChangeDbComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  ...
  isDeleting: boolean = false

  ...
doStuff() {
    this.isDeleting = true

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { db: this.getSelectedDb(), answer: false }
    });

    // if the user clicks away from dialog, result will be undefined
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: DialogData) => {
     if (result?.answer) {
       this.isDeleting = true
       this.mysqlService.dropDb({
         dbname: result.db
       }).subscribe({
         next: () => {
           ...
           this.isDeleting = false
           this.loadData()
         },
         error: (err: Error) => {
           ...
           this.isDeleting = false
         }
       })
     }
    });
  }
}

As you can see the component has a method dropDb() which (now just for testing purposes) immediately change isDeleting to true. However, the property seems to be not detected by Angular change detection system, as the UI doesn't show the spinner.
Could you give some hints about what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

IIRC show is not a valid value for the visibility attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.php. material components have a [hidden] property which you can use for the purpose, they take a boolean

Jesus, I used show in the dev tools and the icon appeared. Why does the spinner appear if I give its visibility show in the developer tools (even if it's wrong) while this is not the case in Angular? Thanks

As specified by Cee McSharpface, I needed to use visible:
<mat-spinner [style.visibility]="isDeleting ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"></mat-spinner>

Not sure why putting show with developer tools it works the same, maybe Angular expects the allowed values and refuses to update the node if passing anything else.
Using @ngIf or [hidden] has the effect of removing the node from the DOM. With visibility it stays there and occupies the space in the tree, avoiding the other elements to occupy the space (when it's not displayed) or be moved a bit when it appears.
